# Best practice for an "empty" component - null? empty div? (A valid React element (or null) must be returned)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm using typescript and react for a project and I have a case of nested components where I only want the inner component to result in content *if* some condition is true.

For example:

```
export const SomeOverview = (info) => {
  ... // some data manipulation
  return (
     <div>
        <div><.... a bunch of stuff</div>
        <SomeDetail data={data}/>
     </div>
  )
}

export const SomeDetail = (info) => {
    ...
    if (<some condition using info) {
        return (
            <div>
                <some content using info>
            </div>
        )
    }
    return null or <div/> ?
}
```

I can't just not return anything if I don't go into the if statement or else I get the react element error.

So for now I had tried putting in an empty div but it seems kind of like a hack. Is there a "better" way of accomplishing?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Returning `null` is the way to go.

From the official documentation:

> In rare cases you might want a component to hide itself even though it
>   was rendered by another component. To do this return null instead of
>   its render output.

https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#preventing-component-from-rendering